# Couldn't create temp table from select query if result empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I want to crate a temp table from select query (My table has many columns, therefore I don't want to create the temp table manually)
I use the following query:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM MyTable
WHERE ...
```

If this query return empty rows, it won't create `#TempTable`. Hence, I cannot use this `#TempTable` for the next queries.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: In my experience, unless you have an error, this _will_ create a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

If the query `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ...` in your code you posted:

```
 SELECT * 
 INTO TempTable 
 FROM MyTable WHERE ...
```

returned no rows, it ***will*** create an empty `TempTable`, but it won't fill any data in it if there is no rows matched the `WHERE` clause. But it should create the table `TempTable` at least with the same structure as the `MyTable` and it will be empty.

For example this:

```
SELECT * INTO TempTable FROM MyTable WHERE 1 <> 1;
```

Will always create an empty table `TempTable` with the same structure as `MyTable` since the predicate `1 <> 1` is always false.

However you can declare it like so:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(Field1 int, ...);
```

Comment: I assume this is a typo as you can't select into a table variable. "SELECT * INTO @TempTable FROM MyTable WHERE 1 <> 1;" will result in the error "Incorrect syntax near '@TempTable'."."

Comment: @brian - Sorry, Yes it is a typo fixed now. I meant a table name not a table variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are dynamically creating and populating temporary table and not creating it explicitly.In such scenario, you must check the existence of the temp table in the beginning before you create one.

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
END

SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM MyTable 
Select * From #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

your query

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM MyTable
WHERE ...
```

will create an empty table if the select returns no rows